# Centered Images group

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been trying to make an album images group, But there is a Big gap in the right side and won't be fit without using Padding, But when i use Padding it only fit for my PC resolution and becomes a bigger gap in other resolutions, Also if there is a picture bigger in resolution than the other images it wont resize itself of the main size, I've tried many ways but i just don't understand what should i change the height and width.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="cards-deck">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <img src="http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/90000/t2/csx-train.jpg" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .card-block {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 16px;
        }

        .card {
            background-color: transparent;
            border-width: 0px;
        }

        .row {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Other devices LOOK
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRwQp.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View Code: http://codepen.io/cbgraphics/pen/GrMYKQ

Looking at your code it appears that you are using Bootstrap. There are some built in tags that you didn't take advantage of.

I rebuilt a similar layout using lots of little tweaks to your code.

First - You need to wrap your content in the container class:
`<div class="container">`

Second - It is better if you put each card in a column div. These will automatically fill in your columns (assuming that the size of your images are all the same. `<div class="col-md-3">`

Third - I changed the padding to keep the grid spacing consistent.

You do not need to create a new row for each image. The current way you are using Bootstrap is trying to override the default functions and CSS that make it awesome.

More about the Bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Your rebuilt version really cleared everything to me now, Thank you. -[ I was wondering If there is a possible way to make all images as the same size? Some times images would be taller\wider by 12px or 17px in height\width, do i just use (col) without md\llg\sm ? or there is a specific way? I've tried changing the card-block res but didn't work correctly.

Comment: Some one much smarter than me figured out how to crop all images so they are square. I'm sure you could change the proportions to get a different size if you wanted.

Updated Code: http://codepen.io/cbgraphics/pen/bgQqXK